# What style options should a mobile app provide?

Tags: settings, style

I have a couple fairly simple Android apps on Google Play. I've gotten a few reviews which somewhat surprised me (though they probably shouldn't have) asking about adding an option to use a light theme, or an option to set font size.

Font size seems like something that shouldn't be adjusted per app in general, since there's a global setting for font size which should provide a reasonable setting for all apps. Light vs. dark theme seems more reasonable; perhaps Android should have an option for users to specify their preference, but that's not available in standard Android as far as I'm aware.

Perhaps it would be best to just implement both these things since they're easy enough (though implementing every feature that someone might like would lead to rather bloated apps). But what would be considered the best practice? Is there any other customization of style that a typical app should offer?

Comment: When you say "typical app" this question is really broad and and can easily become opinion-based. I don't know if specifying app type will narrow this question enough.

Answer (score 1):

It's your app. So eventually you decide. But **I would pick your choice based on what kind of app you have.**

Apps that are mostly used at night or late in the evening (alarm, ASMR etc.) tend to have a dark theme for example while other apps typically have a light or customizable theme.

If you have a notepad app. It might be a nice idea to implement something where you could change the font, but it's not necessary. Same goes for a reading app where you may not want a high-contrast app.

These are just tips but the most important thing is that your app works and having style options is not a must in most occasions.